# Error trying to create table when using read replica cluster in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

After attempting to add a read replica cluster with my primary cluster, I'm seeing

```
Error creating table $TABLE on the master: Not enough live tablet servers to create table with replication factor 1. 0 tablet servers are alive.
```

When I try to create tables, tservers and masters all seem to be running, but I don't see the Registered new tablet server logs as mentioned here. What might be causing tservers to not be able to register with masters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you are creating a read-replica cluster with rf=2 on the read-replica side,

```
./bin/yb-admin -master_addresses ip1:7100,ip2:7100,ip3:7100 add_read_replica_placement_info c.r.z1:1,c.r.z2:1 2 rr
```

or

```
./bin/yb-admin -master_addresses 127.0.0.1:7100,127.0.0.2,127.0.0.3 add_read_replica_placement_info c.r.z1:2 2 rr
```

Notice that we have named this read-replica cluster `rr`.

And now, the tservers for the read-replica must be started with the appropriate `--placement_*` options.

So these 4 gflags: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#geo-distribution-flags

For example, for my 1st example.. the TServers in `z1` should have these additional gflags:

```
--placement_cloud c --placement_region r --placement_zone z1 --placement_uuid rr
```

and the TServers in `z2` should have these:

```
--placement_cloud c --placement_region r --placement_zone z1 --placement_uuid rr
```

For the primary cluster TServers, don't pass that option. Default `--placement_uuid` for those is an empty string. Set it only for the read replica cluster.

Please also check the following admin UI pages:
a) http://master-ip:7000/cluster-config to see if your cluster config looks right
and
b) http://master-ip:7000/tablet-servers to see if tservers are classified correctly between the primary vs. `rr` sub-clusters.